# How to enable realtime analytics after moving app to other account?

Tags: ios, google-fabric

I moved my iOS app from one fabric account to another fabric account.

Everything is working fine, except the realtime analytics.
Fabric keeps saying "Waiting for events"

I enabled debugging

[[Fabric sharedSDK] setDebug: YES];
[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];

And if i look into the logs i see.

```
[Fabric] settings downloaded successfully
[Fabric] Settings are available for consumption
[Fabric] Starting onboarding with app update
Answers] Answers enabled with settings: {
"flush_interval_secs" = 10;
"flush_on_background" = 1;
"forward_to_google_analytics" = 0;
"include_purchase_events_in_forwarded_events" = 0;
"max_byte_size_per_file" = 8000;
"max_file_count_per_send" = 1;
"max_pending_send_file_count" = 100;
"sampling_rate" = 1;
"track_custom_events" = 1;
"track_predefined_events" = 1;
"track_view_controllers" = 0;
url = "https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events";
}
[Answers] Logging events to /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/96A9
```

So everything looks ok, but fabric keeps saying 'Waiting for events' with the animation in the background.

If i just change my bundle id, to something else, submit that app to fabric. Everything works fine. Even the realtime analytics.

Anybody knows why it isn't working with my original Bundle Id?

Comment: Update your fabric key in the app for the new account

Comment: The key is correct. Im sure about this, because if i only change the bundle id, and nothing else. Fabric realtime analytics works perfectly fine.